# Custom rotate a div on click when it is already rotating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm doing is I have a big circle with small circles around it. All of it are inside a div and I am rotating that div.

When I hover on that div, I pause the rotation and what I would like to do next is do a custom rotation based on what small circle is clicked. e.g. 1st circle is clicked, rotate 30deg, 2nd rotate 60deg, and so on. Somehow I'm not able to do that custom rotation. Here are snippets of my code for further info.

HTML

```
<div class='mcA_icon_wrap playing'>
  <div class='mcA_icon_wrap_inner'>

        <ul>
            <li><div class='mcA_icon' id='mcA_icon_1'></div></li>
            <li><div class='mcA_icon' id='mcA_icon_2'></div></li>
            <li><div class='mcA_icon' id='mcA_icon_3'></div></li>       
        </ul>

        <div id='big_circle'>
            <img src='images/big_circle.png'/>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 @-webkit-keyframes r {
 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
 }

.mcA_icon_wrap  {
-ms-animation: r 15s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: r 15s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: r 15s infinite linear;
 animation: r 15s infinite linear; 
 }

.mcA_icon_wrap.playing {
-ms-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
animation-play-state: running;
}

.mcA_icon_wrap.paused {
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
 animation-play-state: paused;
 }
```

JS

```
$(".mcA_icon_wrap").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("playing paused");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("paused playing");
});

$(".mcA_icon").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var idNum = id.split("_");
    var x = parseInt(idNum[2]) * 30;
    $(".mcA_icon_wrap").css({"-webkit-transform": "rotate("+ x +"deg)"});
});
```

The "$(".mcA_icon_wrap").css({"-webkit-transform": "rotate("+ x +"deg)"});" is not working.

After the mouse leaves the div, I want it to continue rotating. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rotate an element that is already rotating. You would have to stop the current animation and start a new one, based on current rotation.

An easier way is to separate rotations, as on [this example I made](http://jsfiddle.net/brunomuller/r9ztnL19/2/). This way the outer element rotates with transition, and the inner element with infinite animation. You set the rotation on js, and the transition on css:

```
.mcA_icon_wrap  {
    ...
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Also, if you would like to apply multiple animations on the same element, consider using a javascript library like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)